# Visit every node using shortest route algorithm

Tags: vb.net, dijkstra, shortest-path

For my A-level computing project I am coding a route planner in VB.
I am planning on implementing Dijkstra's algorithm to do this, but I was wondering if there is a way in which it can find the shortest route, whilst also visiting every node once?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Basically what you want is a solution to the Traveling Salesman Problem? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem Does it have to be Dijkstra's?

Comment: No it doesn't have to be Dijkstra's that was just the initial idea that I had thought of.
Sorry for the late reply